# Using a RestTemplate in a non Web app in SpringBoot app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that is not a web app, that has this piece of code

```
ResponseEntity<GeolocationAddress> response = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(urlStringConnection,
                GeolocationAddress.class);
```

But then I have this error:

```
The import org.springframework.web cannot be 
 resolved
```

so I added this dependency

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But then when I start the app I got this error:

```
Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration due to org/springframework/web/context/support/StandardServletEnvironment not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be a little late, but I had similar issues. By default Spring Boot tries to deduce the type of the application context to use by examining the class path. If it finds either *javax.servlet.Servlet* or *org.springframework.web.context.ConfigurableWebApplicationContext*, it instantiates a *WebApplicationContext*.

To avoid the error you got, I had to do the following in the main method of the app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(App.class)
                .contextClass(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

I also excluded any unwanted AutoConfigure classes in the application.properties :

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.TraceWebFilterAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sendgrid.SendGridAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.SitePreferenceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.SocialWebAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.FacebookAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.LinkedInAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.TwitterAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration,org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.CrshAutoConfiguration
```